# Why does this segfault?

Tags: c, debugging, enums, segmentation-fault

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x08048637 in insertWordDictR (string=0xbf87e7b6 "a", child=0x20f88,
    isTerminal=0x20f8c) at dictionary.c:54
54                        *isTerminal = False;
```

in the header file I have

```
typedef enum {False, True} bool;
```

Here are the related lines of code：

```
dictLink insertWordDictR(char *string, dictLink child, bool* isTerminal){
  dictLink newWord;

  if(isTerminal != NULL){
    if(string[0] == '\0'){
          *isTerminal = True;
          return NULL;
    }else{
          *isTerminal = False;
    }
  }


  if (child == NULL){
      newWord = malloc(sizeof (struct dictEdge));
      newWord->thisChar = string[0];
      newWord->child = insertWordDictR(string + 1, newWord, &(newWord->isTerminal));             
      newWord->sibling = NULL;
  }else{
      newWord = insertIntoSiblingList(string, child);    

  }

  return newWord;
}
```

This line is an example of how I called this function

```
  newWord->child = insertWordDictR(string + 1, newWord, &(newWord->isTerminal));
```

[All files can be found here](http://repository.atwebpages.com/dictionary/), there is also an input file called "testing".

Comment: Post the code where you call your insertWordDictR function, include the definition of all your variables you pass to that function too

Comment: I suggest enabling additional compiler warnings... e.g. if you're using gcc the "-Wall" command-line option would probably have warned about the uninitialized use of "result".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this sequence you are taking the address of a field from an uninitialized pointer, as indicated by the inserted comment:

```
dictLink result;
if(sibling == NULL){
      result = malloc(sizeof (struct dictEdge));
      result->thisChar = string[0];
      result->sibling = NULL;
      result->child = insertWordDictR(string + 1, result, &(result->isTerminal)); 

}else if(string[0] < sibling->thisChar){
      result = malloc(sizeof (struct dictEdge));
      result->thisChar = string[0];
      result->sibling = sibling;
      result->child = insertWordDictR(string + 1, result, &(result->isTerminal));  

  }else if(string[0] == sibling->thisChar){
      /* "result" has not been initialized, &(result->isTerminal) is an invalid pointer */
      sibling->child = insertWordDictR(string + 1, result, &(result->isTerminal)); 
    result = sibling;
```

Answer (score 2):

There might be other errors, but at line 35 in dictionary.c you do:

```
sibling->child = insertWordDictR(string + 1, result, &(result->isTerminal));
```

However, nowhere in that code path is `result` allocated, so you pass an uninitalized pointer to insertWordDictR.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing an invalid pointer as the parameter isTeminal. You'll have to show the call for us to tell you why.

Answer (score 0):

From the segfault, it seems that `string` has a very different address than `isTerminal`.  There is some problem with calling this function, maybe for example you are passing pointer of a variable that is on the stack and for some reason architecture doesn't allow it.

My guess is that `isTerminal` is local variable that you took pointer of, and it went out of scope before calling `insertWorkDictR`.

Hope it helps.